# Парсинг топовых приложений из Itunes (Appstore), используя JSON в Objective-C

Tags: xcode, json, objective-c, iphone

**Задача:** Получить некоторое количество топовых приложений из Айтюнса  с помощью JSON.

**Ход работы:** С начало наткнулся на Itunes rss generator, но при детальном осмотре выяснилось, что этот XML файл не дает рэйтинг, и все скриншоты приложения (дает ссылку только на один скриншот, а надо все скриншоты). Было найдено решение для использования JSON. Тут все как надо, о приложении выдается вся информация. НО напоролся на подводный камень. 
[Тут](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) документация по поиску.

**Подводный камень:** Не знаю, как задать  *term* так, чтобы вывести топовые приложения. Все остальное работает!

Comment: Если прям "горит" - могу предложить костыль: с помощью rss-фида получать названия приложений,  а уже search-request'ом все остальные данные.

Comment: Да, о таком я уже задумывался, на данный момент используюкак костыль другое решение с помощью рсс фида получаю топ приложений, а уже при детальном просмотре приложения использую json от туда вытягиваю все что необходимо, НО это все равно костыль по моему мнению

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал как и задумывал, взял рсс фид распарсил его с помощью NSXML Parser получил все значения кромей рейтинга(выпилить рейтинг так и не получилось так как его попросту нет в рсс фиде, пришлось на это забить). Все значения хранил в NSDictionary и оттуда уже отображал их в UITableView. Добавил еще UINavigationController и по клику на ячейку таблицы переходил в DetailView, где получал как входной параметр строго ID приложения и уже после это применив JSON получал детальную информацию о приложении. Примеры по парсингу и по NSXML Parser можно найти [тут](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) а почитать про поиск можно в самом вопросе.

P.S. Apple предоставляет хорошие, хоть и немного "заумные" исходники.